# Interposing library functions via linker script: other functions cause segfault

Tags: c, linux, printf, ld, ld-preload

I'm currently utilizing the `LD_PRELOAD` trick and am utilizing a linker version script [as detailed in an article on another website](http://nairobi-embedded.org/elf_ld_preload.html). My MCVE code is included below.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE     (1024)


int __printf__(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
    int ret;
    int len;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    vsnprintf(buf, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, fmt, args);

#if 1
    //typeof(vsnprintf) *real_func = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "vsnprintf");
    //(*real_func)(buf, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, fmt, args);
#endif

    len = strlen(buf);
    ret = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, len);
    va_end(args);

    return ret;
}
asm(".symver __printf__, __printf_chk@GLIBC_2.3.4");
```

If I modify my custom `printf` function to simply write a static string, no problems. However, I want to modify the data being sent to the console via `printf` (add a prefix, suffix, and set certain character to UPPERCASE, etc). It seems that whenever I attempt to use any other `printf`-family functions to generate a copy of the user-provided string, I get a segfault, as shown below.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchr.S:32
32  ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchr.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchr.S:32
#1  0x00007ffff78591c8 in __find_specmb (format=0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>) at printf-parse.h:108
#2  _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=s@entry=0x7fffffffc380, format=format@entry=0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>, ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffc4f8) at vfprintf.c:1312
#3  0x00007ffff7882989 in _IO_vsnprintf (string=0x7fffffffc510 "", maxlen=<optimized out>, format=0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>, args=0x7fffffffc4f8)
    at vsnprintf.c:114
#4  0x00007ffff7bd58a1 in __printf__ (fmt=0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>) at libfakeprintf.c:19
#5  0x00000000004004aa in printf (__fmt=0x400644 "%s received %d args\n") at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:104
#6  main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at print_args.c:5
(gdb) quit
```

What is causing this crash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overridden the glibc internal function `__printf_chk` , however this function does not have a prototype that matches printf. It's prototype is:

```
int __printf_chk(int flag, const char * format, ...);
```

So make sure your own `__printf__` function has that prototype too.
There's a brief description of `__printf_chk` [here](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libc---printf-chk-1.html)